# JBehave(+Serenity) index.html not generated in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jbehave, serenity-bdd

When I run my tests in my local machine, report file is always created/overwritten in: C:\Temp\myLocalFolder\target\site\serenity\index.html

But when I run my tests using Jenkins(localhost:8080), report file is Not being generated in: C:\Users\me\.jenkins\workspace\myJenkinsFolder\target\site\serenity

In Jenkins, I've already added the Thucydides plugin, added it in Post-Build Actions, and set Report Path to target/site/serenity. I tried copying the index.html from my local folder to the jenkins folder, and after running I can view the same report. However I want it to be overwritten by the latest run on Jenkins. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apprarently I just had to set Report Path in Jenkins to the same directory as my local folder (C:\Temp\myLocalFolder\target\site\serenity\index.html). I'm not sure if that's the correct approach. It won't work if I run from my online github repository. I will try that one next.